# Expand and Collapse Divs in React

Tags: css, reactjs

The sandbox that is below is showing two expanding and collapsing divs that I'm just testing with for a template. Each one will toggle expand/collapse a div that's hidden on the right side.

What I'm trying to do is make it so that **when you click to expand one div the other will collapse**. What would be the easiest way to add that functionality?

Would really appreciate any advice on logic or a solution to make it work. I'm thinking of maybe setting an handleClick function that says when div "x" is the active div close all others but I'm not entirely sure of the logic or solution here. Would appreciate any help.

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-cherry-pk7xw?file=/src/NavButton.js

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Toggle the menu on click, and close the other one at the same time.

```js
      <div className="iconBox">
        <div
          className="navIcon"
          onClick={() => {
            setToggle(!toggle);
            setToggle1(false);
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
...
      <div className="iconBox2">
        <div
          className="navIcon"
          onClick={() => {
            setToggle1(!toggle1);
            setToggle(false);
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
```

codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-banzai-58snd

Comment: Thank you for your help with that. I appreciate it. My last question is, I'm planning on having four div that'll be getting toggled. Is there any easier way to setup the functionality so I don't have to write four sets of setToggle(false) for each div?

Comment: @GoreSometimes You can have single state for all divs to use only one setState.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, would be able to show me an example of this or point me in the right direction of where I can do so? I believe it would be with useContext but I've only learned the basics of react thus far. Appreciate all of your help. Thank you.

Comment: @GoreSometimes You don't need useContext. Using an array or an object would be fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-fast-nzez8